# Test code from React Book produced the error Module parse failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

```
I was following the instructions in Chapter 1 Page 10 from the **React Projects book by Roy Derks .**The script produced the error

**"ERROR in ./src/index.js 1:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders"
yet still created the Dist folder with the main.js page. However later on it failed to create the index.html in the dist folder, nor did it "add inside my body tag, a new scripts tag that directs us to my application bundle, that is, the dist/main.js file. " (later on in chapter 1 page 14/15 of the book)**
```

*The instructions on Chapter 1 Page 10.*
**Install these packages from npm using the following command:
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli
2. The next step is to include these packages inside the package.json file and have them run in our start and build scripts. To do this, add the start and build scripts to our package.json file:
{ "name": "movieList",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts":
{ _ "start": "webpack --mode development",
+ "build": "webpack --mode production",
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1" },
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
}
"+" symbol is used for the line which is added and "-" symbol is used for the line which is removed in the code**
*The Error.*


ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:10
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|
> const App - () -> {
| return

## movieList

;
| };
webpack 5.21.1 compiled with 1 error in 149 ms
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! movie_list@1.0.0 start: `webpack --mode development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the movie_list@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\green\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-02-07T15_00_52_226Z-debug.log

```
*My package.json*

**{
"name": "movie_list",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack --mode development",
"build": "webpack --mode production",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"  
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.12.13",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.13",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
"babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
"webpack": "^5.21.1","webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"  }
}**

*my webpack.config.js*

**module.exports = {
    module: {
    rules: [   
   {
   test: /\.js$/,
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   use: {
   loader:'"babel-loader', 
                    },         
              },   
          ],    
    }, 
  }
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
template: './src/index.html',
filename: './index.html',
});
module.exports = {
    module: {
    rules: [ 
    {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: { loader: 'babel-loader',        
           },      
       },  
    ],  
 },plugins: [htmlPlugin],
};**

*my .babelrc*
**{
 "presets":    [     
    [
"@babel/preset-env",      
  {
   "targets": {
     "node": "current"       
              }       
        }    
   ],
"@babel/react" 
 ]
}**

*my index.js*

**import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
console.log("movieList")
const App - () -> {
return <h1>movieList</h1>;
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));**
```

Comment: Try const App = () - >{}. What is that "-"?

Comment: `const App = () => {}`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal originally that was the same code that I had, but I was still getting errors. The text book had the code written as "const App -> () ->". I thought that was wrong but said "hey this book suppose to be written by an expert right" glad You posted this, so I know I wasnt wrong originally.

Comment: im still getting the same error, but for line (9:11) ERROR in ./src/index.js 9:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| const App = () => {
>     return <h1>movieList</h1>;
| };
|

Comment: `->` is not a thing in JS. If you are getting errors with `=>` then the problem must be something else. Change to => then see what error message your are getting, and post that here

Comment: I changed it back to =>, and still get the same error, although for line (9:11)
ERROR in ./src/index.js 9:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| const App = () => {
>     return <h1>movieList</h1>;
| };
|

I am started to become suspicious of the book I bought. I double checked and -> is indeed what the book says. It seems someone wrote a typo, so Ill have to be wary of those in the future when using this book.

Comment: @FedericoProvenziani I was following the code example as written in the book, but several people have pointed out the book was wrong, which I thought as well but decided not to question it.

Comment: why do you have a `>` before return now. You need to write `const App = () => {
return <h1>movieList</h1>;
};`